# Issue using forEach on google script

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script

Hi I have a syntax error on a GoogleScript. this is my first script ever so I'm not really sure why is not working. The idea is to pick up information from a google sheet and create a label from a doc template and storage it in a folder

```
function readSheet() {

const labelFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("1NTnJgjCewcFcrtMsl5DtRgrvFUNCdsvt"); 

const docFile = DriveApp.getFileById("1pRy9BLDuDka7-9PKnHGgO1AtgpoWIY45t7ypVhXXM8I");

const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.gettActiveSpreadSheet().getSheetByName("test");

const data = sheet.getRange(2,1,sheet.getLastRow()-1,10).getValues();

  data.forEach(row => {

      shippinglabels(row [5],row [6],row [8],docFile,labelFolder);
});

}

function shippinglabels(user,address,package,docFile,labelFolder) {
   
  
  const labelFile = docFile.makeCopy(labelFolder);

  const tempDocFile = DocumentApp.openById(labelFile.getId());

  const body = tempDocFile.getBody();

  body.replaceText("{user}", user);

  body.replaceText("{address}", address);

  body.replaceText("{package}", package);

  tempDocFile.setName(user);

  tempDocFile.saveAndClose(); 
  

     
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Where is the syntax error?

Comment: Are you using [v8 runtime](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/v8-runtime)? It's defaulted to stable

Answer (score 1):

Please modify as follows and test it again.

#### From:

```
const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.gettActiveSpreadSheet().getSheetByName("test");
```

#### To:

```
const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("test");
```

- In this case, `gettActiveSpreadSheet()` is `getActiveSpreadsheet()`.
- I think that after above modification was reflected to your script, when the folder ID, Google Document ID and the values from Google Spreadsheet are correct, no error occurs. When other error occurred, can you provide the detail information about it? I would like to confirm it.

#### Reference:

- [getActiveSpreadsheet()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#getactivespreadsheet)

Comment: Thanks for the comment, modify what you said but still the same error as before.

When I try to save the script , doesn't save and highlight "data.forEach(row => {" and said as error Syntax error. (line 14, file "Test"). That is the line for the forEach.

Comment: @Aloe Francisco Thank you for replying. In your case, in addition of above modification, I think that you doesn't enable V8 runtime as [Thum Choon Tat have already said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62949007/issue-using-foreach-on-google-script/62949304?noredirect=1#comment111318584_62949007). So how about enabling V8 runtime at the script editor and test it again?

Answer (score 1):

I change the forEach form this:

```
data.forEach(row => {
    
          shippinglabels(row [5],row [6],row [8],docFile,labelFolder);
    });
```

To this:

```
    data.forEach(function(row) {
      shippinglabels(row [5],row [6],row [8],docFile,labelFolder);
});
```

and did the job.

Thanks for the help